# Allowing 3rd party access to your code

Tags: magento, sharing

we are working on a big Magento build and the client wants to bring in a contractor developer to finish off and help test. Obviously, this means accessing our code and customer API. Does anyone have a document they ask 3rd parties to sign for accessing your code? Protecting it?

Comment: Like a [non-disclosure agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.